# How to download attendance record with specified time via zkemkeeper

Tags: c#, interop, biometrics

I m using zkemkeeper.dll to download attendance record from biometric device.

```
if (axCZKEM1.ReadGeneralLogData(iMachineNumber))//read all the attendance records to the memory
{   
   while (axCZKEM1.SSR_GetGeneralLogData(iMachineNumber, out idwEnrollNumber, out idwVerifyMode
        , out idwInOutMode, out idwYear, out idwMonth, out idwDay, out idwHour, out idwMinute, out idwSecond, ref idwWorkCode))//get records from the memory
   {
    //code here   
   }
}
```

My question is how can I download attendance record with specified time (date range) via zkemkeeper.
The function ReadGeneralLogData loads all the record from the device which is taking too much time which nearly hangs the device as device contains more than 15 thousand records.
Also don't know how to use GetDataFile function, i mean where it saves the file.
Please help

Answer (score 4):

I had a similar problem and I had to solve it this way. In case your application is using a database or file based data store, you can clear the log of the device **after you save all your data**.

```
if (axCZKEM1.ReadGeneralLogData(iMachineNumber))//read all the attendance records to the memory
{   
   while (axCZKEM1.SSR_GetGeneralLogData(iMachineNumber, out idwEnrollNumber, out idwVerifyMode
        , out idwInOutMode, out idwYear, out idwMonth, out idwDay, out idwHour, out idwMinute, out idwSecond, ref idwWorkCode))//get records from the memory
   {
    //save your data here   
   }

//after that you clear the machine log
    if (axCZKEM1.ClearGLog(iMachineNumber))
    {
        axCZKEM1.RefreshData(iMachineNumber);//the data in the device should be refreshed
        message = "All att Logs have been cleared from teiminal!, Success";
    }
    else
    {
        axCZKEM1.GetLastError(ref idwErrorCode);
        message = "Operation failed, ErrorCode = " + idwErrorCode.ToString();
    }


}
```

This way your next download will be ***much faster*** and the clear operation as well. You are going to be able to download all log data from the device every time you need and of course you can filter your data once is stored in your database.

The users don't know if the log data is in the device or in the database beleave me. Which is important is the data is stored somewhere and the users can see it.

Comment: Keep in mind that if between record download and clear someone uses the terminal, then this record will be lost, you can use the terminal lock function to mitigate the problem.

Answer (score 3):

By default zkemkeeper.dll won't support "download attendance records between specified date range". For this you have to use customized SDK from ZK

Comment: Ganpathi plz elaborate your answer plz.

Comment: Can you tell us where can we find that holy customized SDK from ZK?

Comment: @Ganapathi, there is no customized sdk to provide from zk. only standard sdk is available at their website

Answer (score 1):

I got a solution download attendance record with **specified time (date range)** via `zkemkeeper`.

```
If idwYear.ToString() = Date1.Value.Year.ToString() And idwMonth.ToString() = Date1.Value.Month.ToString() And idwDay.ToString() = Date1.Value.Day.ToString() Then
             //type coding
End If
```

Comment: Could you please elaborate more your answer adding a little more description about the solution you provide?

Comment: You still download the complete data from the devices and filter out the data with the conditional block.

Answer (score 0):

try this..

```
lstMachineInfo = manipulator.GetLogData(objZkeeper,int.Parse(tbxMachineNumber.Text.Trim()));
String dtFrom = dateFrom.Value.ToShortDateString();
String dtTo = dateTo.Value.ToShortDateString();

List<MachineInfo> newList = list.Where(x => x.DateOnlyRecord >= dateFrom.Value.AddDays(-1) && x.DateOnlyRecord <= dateTo.Value).ToList();
ShowStatusBar(newList.Count() + " records found !!", true); 
dataGridView.DataSource = newList;
```

Answer (score -1):

first of all you have to get read all the records of the memory..
then i created one form using one date time picker and one button.
now you have to equal the machine date and selected date.
finally you write the save function coding

Answer (score -1):

save it to your database after fetch then Select * FROM Where Like